# Shopify App hosted in Heroku getting iframe error

Tags: php, heroku, shopify

Im using an embeded app (Node+react) when a customer is redirected to billing page ,Im facing an iframe error.

```
Refused to display 'https://lancome-staging.myshopify.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

I have deployed the App in Heroku and Shopify consultant told me its not a problem related to code rather than an issue in Heroku Server settings.
How can i edit the headers in Heroku and which file do i have to edit and how can i access it ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyNqV.png)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are seeing NGROK at Heroku is most troubling. A deployment to Heroku is production code, and in no way, shape, or form, should there be any connections to NGROK. It seems your developer may either have deployed development code to Heroku, or perhaps you deployed a developer API set of keys to Heroku? Either way, ensure you have deployed production code and production API keys to Heroku.

Comment: well this is my local development thats why i have the ngrok route ,but im facing the same error in heroku app

Comment: Have your developer fix their code. It is not your problem if you are not the developer. They are doing things wrong if they are getting header errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy the app to heroku you need to make sure that all the URLs you were using in the local environment are replaced.

1. You need to update (or add) the heroku URLs under your app in shopify.dev
2. You need to update the environment variable using `heroku config:edit` so that the variable that you used (typically `HOST`) is pointing to the heroku URL

Once you're sure that you never put your ngrok URL in the code, at least, you should have a different error.

Comment: I would add to your comment that this technique, changing App settings is really not a good pattern. Instead, always setup a pair of API keys. One for localhost development, pointing at NGROK, where you can test with development stores, and another pair pointing at Heroku. Otherwise, one codebase cannot easily be tested. Your only choice is to push edits to heroku, which is living dangerously.

Comment: @DavidLazar yep, agree. That's a good advice.

Comment: @DavidLazar 
Refused to display 'https://lancome-staging.myshopify.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. 
This is the error i face when i deploy to live

Comment: You probably need to redirect outside of the frame, I suggest you to check the react template app of Shopify to see how the authentication is made.

Comment: i did but nothing works and a shopify consultant told me i have to edit the server settings in heroku.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyNqV.png 
Pls check the image 
@FabioFilippi

Comment: You are still inside the myshopify domain. You need to redirect outside of that scope. Please try to run the template app of shopify to see how that works. If you are using react it's easier if you just copy and paste the auth  middleware.

Comment: return   ctx.redirect(redirecturl);
This is Server.js wroted using node.js